# Apache2 configuration issue?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd

Why is it that when I write the directive `Alias /hello /myfile.php` it works fine, but if I write `Alias /hello /myfile.php?myvar=test` apache gives me 'NOT FOUND'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html), the alias target can only be a file or path. Is suspect you don't have a file literally called `myfile.php?myvar=test` on your filesystem.

You might be able to do this with [rewrite rules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/), but in this case, it sounds much easier to handle the default parameter in your script itself.

Comment: Alternatively, the OP could probably `RedirectMatch ^/hello$ /myfile.php?myvar=test`, but this is not invisible to the end user.

Comment: Yes, good point but that seems more "intrusive" as you say than a rewrite (or not modifying the URL at all and handling in the program). Not really sure this is on topic here actually.